# how to convert time values (in string) to datetime in python?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

so I've been trying to work on a statement where i am supposed to take in time value from the user and if it is between certain time values, I am supposed to greet the user with good morning!, good after noon, good evening and good night. The user will input time in the format HH:MM:SS.
my code for the function looks something like this:

```
r = datetime.time(12, 00, 00)
t = datetime.time(18, 00, 00)
u = datetime.time(6, 00, 00)
p = datetime.time(23, 59, 00)
def my_function:
time=input('what is the time?')
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')>=u and datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')<r:
        print('Morning')
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')>=r and datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')<t:
        print('Afternoon')
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')>=t and datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')<p:
        print('Evening')
    elif datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')>=p and datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S')<u:
        print('Night')
    else:
        return 'invalid'
```

i am returned with the error time data 'what is the time?' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' when i try to call the function. Can anyone give any suggestion on how to modify my code or what i am doing wrong? thanks in advance

edit:
It gives the error '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: probably you mean `time = input("what is the time?")`

Comment: it now gives the error '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_function():

    r = datetime.time(12, 00, 00)
    t = datetime.time(18, 00, 00)
    u = datetime.time(6, 00, 00)
    p = datetime.time(23, 59, 00)

    time = input('what is the time?')
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M:%S').time()

    if u <= time < r:
        return('Morning')
    elif r <= time < t:
        return('Afternoon')
    elif t <= time < p:
        return('Evening')
    elif p <= time or time < u:
        return('Night')
    else:
        return 'invalid'

 print(my_function())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `input('what is the time')` so your variable is the string question instead of whatever you're typing into the terminal/calling your function.
In addition, the code above needs an indentation after the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = input('What is the time?"
```

right now, you're setting time equal to a python tuple with one string inside of it... "Where is the time?". A tuple is kind of like a list, but with () instead of [].

When you pass the variable 'time' to datetime, what you're literally passing is this: ("What is the time?")

It shouldn't return an error on passing anything to datetime unless it's already asked the user for input.